# recursive directive and ng-init on ng-repeat fails to detect scope change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I spent a lot of time detecting this one, and I'm just wondering if someone has an explanation to help my understanding. In turn it might help others that run into this issue...

As a recursive directive, when attempting to use ng-init on the ng-repeat, any change to the scope will not be detected. However if you set the new value when you recursively call your directive this works. There must be something I didn't understand about `ng-init`, yet failed to find anything that could furthur my understanding of this issue.

The jsfiddle is here, just comment out one section inside the directive to see it fail while the other works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/DsvX6/41/

In brief:

This would fail, although adding a $watch within this scope will be detected, it will not trigger the directive to refresh it's view. Note here the `ng-init` on the `ng-repeat`.

```
    '<ul>' + 

        // does not work
        '<li class="tree" ng-repeat="(key, val) in names" ng-init="values=values[key]">' +
        '<div>{{key}} <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="values.set"></div>' +
        '<tree names="val" values="values"></tree>' +
        '</li>' +

    '</ul>';
```

The only way I got this to work was the following, here note the recursive value passed is not within an ng-init, rather it's on the directives (named "

```
    '<ul>' + 

        // works
        '<li class="tree" ng-repeat="(key, val) in names">' +
        '<div>{{key}} <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="values[key].set"></div>' +
        '<tree names="val" values="values[key]"></tree>' +
        '</li>' +

    '</ul>';
```

Again, if anyone can explain this to better my understanding, or others coming across this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand entirely but a couple of things.  Check the docs on ng-init, they prescribe it only be used for nested ng-repeats for setting up a unique name for the $index for each loop and otherwise recommend not using it.  I believe ng-init as it's name implies will only execute 1 time as an initialization though I haven't dug into the code to confirm.

Comment: shaunhusain: interesting point, I did read that part, and probably focused mostly on 'recursive'. But it would seem that it only operates on the ng-repeat reference, and not that of any others. In other words, $index is not carried over to ng-init.